# Gradle disable all incremental compilation and parallel builds

Tags: java, gradle, protocol-buffers

In a small set of sbt projects we needed a protobuf/grpc compilation, and because only Gradle has normal support for that we used it to just do the protobuf related tasks.

Sometimes it will randomly fail compiling the very same thing and will succeed on retry, we determined that its because of incremental Java compilation.

I want to disable all sorts of incubating features and incremental compilations, I want this thing to be deterministic.

For that I tried

```
compileJava {
    //enable compilation in a separate daemon process
    options.fork = false

    //enable incremental compilation
    options.incremental = false
}
```

but Gradle will still give output like this (apparently ignoring those flags)

```
Parallel execution is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:deleteGeneratedSource
:clean
:extractIncludeProto
:extractProto UP-TO-DATE
:generateProto
:recompileProto
```

**So how do we disable parallel execution and incremental Java compilation?**

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? It's causing my build to take forever.

Comment: i got rid of gradle and sbt, both are making life more complicated... maven rocks it without bothering you too much, yes it takes longer to build but intellij does not rely on maven or sbt or gradle to do incremental fast compliactions all by itself... so benefit of other build tools is questionable... when developing you dont need to compile using mvn anyway...

for complex scripts we have few kotlin functions that do all the work those fancy build tools are supposed to do with much less effor and greater flexibility...

Comment: @robin-green: since you’ve started a bounty on this question, could you perhaps elaborate on what would qualify as an acceptable answer for you? TBH, I find the original question rather vague; I don’t even see how the currently accepted answer could have answered the question at some point … Maybe it’s because I’m not facing such a non-determinism myself; would you be able to provide a [mcve] that exhibits the occasional non-determinism?

Comment: My use case is not the same as for the OP, but I still want to disable all parallelism in a gradle run - ideally all forked processes - or if not, then all simultaneously-running forked processes that are running JUnit tests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to add

```
org.gradle.daemon=false
org.gradle.parallel=false
```

to the `gradle.properties` file, it can help you in your problem.

Comment: This doesn't work with Gradle 4.6. Even the solution mentioned here (https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1827) does not work.

Answer (score 14):

**Parrallel building is not enabled by default in Gradle**. That said, in order to explicitly disable parrallelism, you can add

```
org.gradle.parallel=false
```

to your project's gradle.properties file or specify the **--no-parallel** option to the gradle/gradlew command that initiates the build.

**Important note here**, is that for certain versions of Gradle, like 4.6 and 4.7 and others, disabling parallel execution did not work. **A workaround is to specify a very limited number of worker threads**. By default the max worker threads are equal to the number of your system's processors.

So in the project's gradle.properties add the value

```
org.gradle.workers.max=1
```

in order to limit the number of concurrent worker threads to 1 or specify the option **--max-workers=1** to the gradle/gradlew command that initiates the build.

**In versions prior to Gradle 4.10, incremental building is not enabled by default**. For versions after 4.10, you can add the following to your build.gradle (most probably to the top-level one in a multi-module project) in order to disable incremental Java compilation:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.incremental = false
}
```