# React Native Android build issue

Tags: android, react-native

I am facing build issue while running "npx react-native run-android" on my windows.

I am stuck with this. Please guide me what I need to do.

I tried following options

- deleting .gradle and rebuilding
- deleting node-modules and do npm i
- deleting androidResources

````
w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build\kotlin\sessions

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.           

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
74 actionable tasks: 45 executed, 29 up-to-date
                                                                                                                                                    
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                    
* What went wrong:                                                                                                                                  
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.                                                                                                      
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable                              
   > java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\HP\Desktop\projects\MyEventors\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\packageDebug\tmp\debug\zip-cache\androidResources (Access is denied)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 55s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.     
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\HP\Desktop\projects\MyEventors\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\packageDebug\tmp\debug\zip-cache\androidResources (Access is denied)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 55s

    at makeError (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\projects\MyEventors\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\HP\Desktop\projects\MyEventors\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\projects\MyEventors\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\projects\MyEventors\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:142:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.```
````

Answer (score 1):

Try following step

1. Delete android build folders (both `android/build` & `android/app/build`)
2. Add `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m` in `android/gradle.properties`
3. Delete `node_modules`
4. Clean npm / yarn (whichever you are using to install packages) cache by running `npm cache clean --force` / `yarn cache clean`
5. run `npm install` / `yarn` to install packages
6. Android studio -> File -> Invalidate Cache -> Invalidate and Restart
7. Rebuild the project

Comment: I did all the above steps and did run ```npx react-native run-android```. But still same issue.

Comment: I have updated the answer. If that doesn't work, can you try the solutions mentioned here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/65157720/10657559

Comment: This also doesn't fix my issue.

Comment: I got fix. It was because of antivirus or windows firewall defender access issue.

Thanks for support.